# Storing array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, html

I have a quiz page with multiple questions, the page shows 1 question at a time. The answers to the question are displayed in buttons. Whenever a button is pressed the second question is grabbed from the database and is shown. I have a script that puts the value of the pressed button in an array, but when the page is reloaded the array is emptied. I was told to use localstorage but I have no clue how this works, this is my code I use to store data in the array at the moment:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

           var antwoordenObject1= new Array();
            $('.btn').click(function() {
                 antwoordenObject1.push($(this).val());

                  alert("newArray contents = "+ antwoordenObject1);

            });
       });
```

and I found this code to put an array into localstorage but don't know how to combine these two:

```
var complexdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

// store array data to the localstorage
localStorage.setItem("list_data_key",  JSON.stringify(complexdata));

//Use JSON to retrieve the stored data and convert it 
var storedData = localStorage.getItem("complexdata");
if (storedData) {
  complexdata = JSON.parse(storedData);

}
document.write(complexdata);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
       var antwoordenObject1 = localStorage.getItem("antwoorden");
       antwoordenObject1 = antwoordenObject1 ? JSON.parse(antwoordenObject1) : [];
       $('.btn').click(function() {
           antwoordenObject1.push($(this).val());
           localStorage.setItem("antwoorden",  JSON.stringify(antwoordenObject1));
           alert("newArray contents = "+ antwoordenObject1);

       });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! you saved me a lot of time, trying to get this to work for a long time now.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `.setItem()` and `.getItem()` methods of `localStorage`.

**Note:** LocalStorage can only store strings. So if you try:

```js
var a = {
  test: "foo"
}

localStorage.setItem("test", a);
```

it will store `[object Object]` and not object itself. For arrays, it would be comma separated string.

You will have to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` as well to communicate properly.